# How to display a string with quotes in racket Beginning Student

Tags: string, scheme, racket

How do i display <"> (double quote) as part of a string in Racket?

for example i want to make a string called "apple"
Note: the double quotes are part of the string.

I read that you can escape the quote with \ like "\"apple\"" which gives the output \"apple\"

How can i just get the double quotes alone as part of the string?

NOTE: I am using the Beginning Student language of DrRacket and would prefer if the answer also follow the same lang.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning student language you can do this:

```
> (string-append "\"" "apple" "\"")
"\"apple\""
```

Note that the interaction window *prints* the resulting string with `\"`.
In order to *display* the string to a user, one normally uses `display`.
That is not available until the advanced student language however:

```
> (display (string-append "\"" "apple" "\""))
"apple"
```

Comment: so is there no way in the beginning student language to display the <"> without also displaying the <\> in the interaction window? 
Also if i were to convert the string to an image using the `text` function, would the backslash also be converted to the image?

Comment: The `\"` used only when printing a string in the repl. It means that the character `"` is a part of the string. The `text` function takes the individual characters and draws their symbols - so no problems there. As far as I know you cannot display strings in the beginning student language, but your idea of using `text` to make an image will work fine.

Comment: yes i just checked it myself and the `text` works fine with your solution. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

(string-append "\"" "string" "\"")

Will display "string"

Comment: This repeats the information in the other answer, but with less content and does not provide an alternative ([From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13876116)).